# Ошибка при загрузке фото через ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Ошибка в загрузке возникает если в имени картинки есть одна или больше точек например: `72247.343.jpg` или `fon.image.jpg` не могу найти в скрипте какая функция отвечает за это.

И если можно при загрузке название (`001.JPG`) сделать до нижнего регистра (`001.jpg`).

У меня форма загрузки через `ajax` использует `jquery.form.js` может проблема где-то в `jquery.form.js`.

**Html**:

```
<div class="bloc_upload">   
    <form id="photo-frm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">       
        <div id="preview99" class="file_upload">    
            <img src="css/img/delete.png" alt="Remove file" class="clear-image" id="" title="" width="30" height="30" />
            <img src="css/img/default.png" class="default" alt="Фото Незагрузилось !!!" id="file-preview"  />           
            <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" />
            <input type="submit" id="upload-submit" name="Upload"  value="Upload_photo" />  
        </div>      
    </form>
</div>
```

**Js**:

```
$(function(){   
   // Options for Ajax submittion
    var options = { 
        beforeSubmit: showRequest, 
        beforeSend: function()
        { $('#file-preview').attr('src', 'css/img/upload_send.png'); },
        success: showResponse , 
        url: 'upload_image.php',
        type: 'POST'   
    }; 

    // bind to the form's submit event 
    $('#photo-frm').submit(function() { 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
        return false; 
    }); 

    // Before submitting
    function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {        
        // TODO: Do some validation before submitting
    } 

    // After submitting
    function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
        // Preview file
        $('#file-preview').attr('src', './uploads/' + responseText);

        //$('#name-image').html(responseText); 
        $('.clear-image').attr('id', responseText);   


        // Assign file path to hidden input to be saved
        $('#image-name-text').val(responseText);
        // Show X image to clear-image image
        $('.clear-image').show();
    }           

    $('#photo').change(function(){
        // submit form
        $('#photo-frm').submit();
        $('#photo').hide();
    });

    // Remove picture clicked
    $('.clear-image').click(function(){
        // TODO: Remove file from server

        // Remove preview image
        $('#file-preview').attr('src', 'css/img/default.png');
        // Clear hidden and file input
        $('#photo').val('');
        $('#image-name-text').val('');      
        $('#fil').html('Файл не выбран');   

        // Hide X image 
        $('.clear-image').hide();  
        $('#photo').show();
    });
});
```

**upload_image.php**:

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png"); 
$uploads = "./uploads/" ; 

if ( $_FILES['photo']['name'] ) 
{  
$name = $_FILES['photo']['name'];    
$size = $_FILES['photo']['size'];   

if (strlen($name)) {
list($sometext, $extension) = explode(".", $name); 
if (in_array($extension, $valid_formats))        
{       
    if ($size < (2048 * 1024))    
    { 
        $imagename = time() . "." . $extension;
        $tmp = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, $uploads . $imagename)) {       
            echo $imagename;
        } else {        
        $imagename = "erorr/erorr_image.jpg";
        echo $imagename;
        }           
    } else {    
    $imagename = "erorr/erorr_2Mb.jpg";
    echo $imagename;
    }       
} else {    
    $imagename = "erorr/erorr_format.jpg";
    echo $imagename;
}   
} else { 
echo "Выберите фото...!"; 
}   
exit();
}
```

Еще нужно подключить библиотеку `jquery-1.9.0.min.js` и `jquery.form.js`

Comment: обратите внимание на эту строчку: `list($sometext, $extension) = explode(".", $name);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в строке

```
list($sometext, $extension) = explode(".", $name);
```

для примеров когда с имени файла несколько точек - `explode` вернет массив с более чем двумя элементами, но в переменные запишутся только первый и второй.

Для решения можно воспользоваться функцией [*`end`*](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.end.php)

```
$extension = end(explode(".", $name));
```